# Rails 4, Devise and adding confirmable to User Model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, devise

I'm attempting to add password verification to my application.  I've been following the directions on the [Devise Wiki](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Add-:confirmable-to-Users) but when I attempt the migration I get the following error:

```
== 20150127183211 AddConfirmableToDevise: migrating ===========================
-- add_column(:users, :confirmation_token, :string)
rake aborted!
StandardError: An error has occurred, this and all later migrations canceled:

PG::DuplicateColumn: ERROR:  column "confirmation_token" of relation "users" already exists
: ALTER TABLE "users" ADD "confirmation_token" character varying/Users/esteban/Code/rails/ComicBookDB/db/migrate/20150127183211_add_confirmable_to_devise.rb:4:in `up'
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::DuplicateColumn: ERROR:  column "confirmation_token" of relation "users" already exists
: ALTER TABLE "users" ADD "confirmation_token" character varying
/Users/esteban/Code/rails/ComicBookDB/db/migrate/20150127183211_add_confirmable_to_devise.rb:4:in `up'
PG::DuplicateColumn: ERROR:  column "confirmation_token" of relation "users" already exists
/Users/esteban/Code/rails/ComicBookDB/db/migrate/20150127183211_add_confirmable_to_devise.rb:4:in `up'
Tasks: TOP => db:migrate
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

However, I do not see `confirmation_token` reflected in `schema.rb`.  Perhaps I should reset my database?  If so, what is the easiest way to do so?  Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on how you installed your current database.

If you made it with `rake db:create`/`rake db:migrate` - there should be a migration with corresponding fields(maybe removed/modified, they can not magically appear).

If you setup your db using someones dump - it explains how fields appeared in db, but not in schema.

If you are in development mode and have no valuable information in database, easiest way is to re-create your db from scratch:

```
rake db:drop:all
rake db:create:all
rake db:migrate
```

If you have valuable information or your migrations don't fully represent current state of db(maybe you removed some of the migrations or use dumps in team to share information), just skip the step with fields creation in instructions since you already have them.